# Need explanation about Theorem-3.17 in Rudin?

Tags: real-analysis

While proving part(a) of the theorem in case-$3$, how can $-\infty$ be a upper bound of a series, when it itself in a lower bound of all real numbers. Can anyone please provide an example for part(b)

**Theorem**- Let $\{s_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $E$ be the set containing all subsequential limits($-\infty$ and $+\infty$ possibly) and $S_*= \sup E$. Then $s_*$ has the following two properties:

(a) $s_*\in E$.

(b) If $x>s_*$, there is an integer $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $s_n<x$.

Moreover, $s_*$ is the only number with the properties (a) and (b).

**Here is Rudin's proof**

(a) If $s_*=+\infty$, then $E$ is not bounded above; hence $\{s_n\}$ is not bounded above, and there is a subsequence $\{s_{nk}\}$ such that $s_{nk}\to+\infty$.

If $s_*$ is real, then $E$ is bounded above, and at least one subsequential limit exists, so that (a) follows from Theorems 3.7 and 2.28. [I'll state these theorems after the proof. ]

If $s_*=−\infty$, then $E$ contains only one element, namely $−\infty$, and there is no subsequential limit. Hence, for any real $M$, $s_n>M$ for at most a finite number of values of $n$, so that $s_n\to-\infty$.

This establishes (a) in all cases.

(b) Suppose there is a number $x>s_*$ such that $s_n\ge x$ for infinitely many values of $n$. In that case, there is a number $y\in E$ such that $y\ge x>s_*$, contradicting the definition of $s_*$.

Thus $s_*$ satisfies both (a) and (b).

To show the uniqueness, suppose there are two numbers, $p$ and $q$, which satisfy (a) and (b), and suppose $p<q$. Choose $x$ such that $p<x<q$. Since $p$ satisfies (b), we have $s_n<x$ for $n\ge N$. But then $q$ cannot satisfy (a).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  In (a), $-\infty$ is the upper bound not of the sequence $\{s_n\}$ but of the set $E$ of subsequential limits

Comment: As an example of what @J.W.Tanner said: Consider $s_n = -n$. All subsequences of $s_n$ converge to $-\infty$ and so, $-\infty$ is the only subsequential limit. In particular, it is the $\sup$ of all subsequential limits.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, can you also please explain (b), I am stuck from last 2 days, but couldn't find a simpler explanation.

Comment: For (b), we're trying to show that given$x>s_*$, our sequence $\{s_n\}$ eventually stays below $x$. To show this, we use the contrapositive (which means we are trying to show $A\to B$, and we do this by showing $\neg B\to\neg A$). So we say that there are infinitely many $s_n$ which at least as large as $x$. Then we make that sequence, and its limit is going to be greater than $s_*$. But since $s_*$ is the largest limit, this is a contradiction. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to be now.